# Permutation Algorithm OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, algorithm, memory-management, permutation

Please help me to how to fix OutOfMemory exception using below code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Permutation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreatePartsByFreezingEachElementOnce("abcedfghijk");

            PrintPossiblePermutations(false);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------");

            PrintPossiblePermutations(true);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void PrintPossiblePermutations(bool unique)
        {
            var allPermutations = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in _listWithFreezedKey)

                if (item.Item2.Count() == 2)
                {
                    allPermutations.Add(Swap(String.Join(",", item.Item1), item.Item2[0], item.Item2[1]));
                    allPermutations.Add(Swap(String.Join(",", item.Item1), item.Item2[1], item.Item2[0]));
                }

            if (unique)
            {
                var uniuePermutations = allPermutations.Distinct();
                //   PrintPermutations(uniuePermutations.ToList());
                Console.WriteLine(uniuePermutations.Count());
            }
            else
            {
                //    PrintPermutations(allPermutations);
                Console.WriteLine(allPermutations.Count());
            }

        }

        static void PrintPermutations(List<string> permutations)
        {
            int i = 1;
            foreach (var item in permutations)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}    :{1}", i, item));
                i++;
            }
        }

        static List<Tuple<List<char>, List<char>>> _listWithFreezedKey = new List<Tuple<List<char>, List<char>>>();
      static void CreatePartsByFreezingEachElementOnce(string str, List<char> indexToFreeze = null)
                    {
                        List<Tuple<List<char>, List<char>>> _innerlistWithFreezedKey = new List<Tuple<List<char>, List<char>>>();


                        var arr = str.ToCharArray().ToList();
                        var copy = arr;
                        if (indexToFreeze == null)
                        {
                            indexToFreeze = new List<char>();
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            copy = str.ToCharArray().ToList();
                            var nth = arr[i];
                            copy.RemoveAt(i);

                            indexToFreeze.Add(nth);

                            _listWithFreezedKey.Add(new Tuple<List<char>, List<char>>(indexToFreeze.ToList(), copy));
                            _innerlistWithFreezedKey.Add(new Tuple<List<char>, List<char>>(indexToFreeze.ToList(), copy));

                            indexToFreeze.RemoveAt(indexToFreeze.Count() - 1);
                        }

                        foreach (var item in _innerlistWithFreezedKey)
                        {                              
                                List<char> l = item.Item2;
                                CreatePartsByFreezingEachElementOnce(String.Join("", l), item.Item1);
                         }


                        }

        static string Swap(string frezedPart, char swapChar1, char swapChar2)
        {
            return frezedPart + "," + swapChar1 + "," + swapChar2;
        }
    }
}
```

If you run this code using 10 chrs, it throws out of memory exception. But for 9 chars , it returns result.

It was my interview question to write a code such that it should not go out of memory if big data passed.

Thanks,

Comment: `It was my interview question to how should I write this code such that it should not go out of memory.` - So, what is your suspicion? Have you made an improvements?

Comment: Hi rob, Firstly I had to write the algorithm to display all the permutations and second was to look at memory management. I have written This algorithm and it gives correct output but need suggestions on how can I improve it to not to have memory exception.

Comment: FYI- Above code my code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you want to generate *all* permutations at once, instead of generating them one-by-one. You are looking for an algorithm which produces the *next* permutation.

See the first page of [Knuth's book](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc2b.pdf) on generating permutations.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am doing the same thing of book. Freezing each element once and move other parts . But question is more about memory mngt.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my question by myself because it may help someone as well.

I will use Iterator Design Pattern to remove unused elements from memory and will convert collection into sequence.

Thanks,